# wso2is ability to place JWT on the Url instead of the Header

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am evaluating wso2is and trying to use OpenID Connect and specifically JWT tokens functionality.

The issue I am facing is at least one third party applications are requiring the JWT token to be sent on the Url rather than on the preferred Http Header (which wso2is does). I have talked to the third party support about this issue, but have no confidence on when they will fix the issue. Is it possible to configure wso2is to send the JWT token on the Url as well as on the Http Header?

Example of the JWT token on the Url: http://test.example/com/access/jwt?jwt=[JWTToken]

Many Thanks

Comment: Okay. So what you want is to get the OpenID connect JWT token in the URL itself right?

Comment: Yes, exactly correct. I am trying to integrate with Zendesk which will only accept a JWT token on the url. See https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203663816-Setting-up-single-sign-on-with-JWT-JSON-Web-Token- which explains the format it wants.

Comment: There's no straight forward way to get the JWT token in the URL format you need at once. What you can do is get an id_token issued by the IS to a callback location. Then from the callback location simply create the URL in the required format and send to Zendesk